# Python web scraping: failed to write to file after scraping

Tags: python, file-io

I was practicing web scraping by myself and trying to scrape an online novel series by python, from a Chinese online novel website. After I put my python code in a function, it seems to go off.
I wrote a piece of code like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://www.51shucheng.net/zh-tw/wuxia/shediaoyingxiongzhuan')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')

page_list = soup.find_all(class_='mulu-list')
pages = page_list[0].find_all('a')
print(pages[0])

for i in range(len(pages)):
    pages[i] = pages[i].get('href')
    

with open("射雕英雄傳1.txt", "w+") as file_object:
    for i in range(len(pages)):
        file_object.write('\n\n\t{}'.format(i+1))
        page = requests.get(pages[i])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
        content = soup.find(class_='neirong').text
        print(content[0:20])
        file_object.write(content)


with open('射雕英雄傳1.txt') as oldfile, open('射雕英雄傳.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not ('adsbygoogle' in line):
            newfile.write(line)
```

And it works perfectly. However, I want to enclose it in a function, and thus I made the following amendment. It then fails to work: the '射雕英雄傳1.txt' file is still created, but it is empty.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def scraping_novel(prefix,bookname):
    page = requests.get('https://www.51shucheng.net/zh-tw/wuxia/{}'.format(prefix))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
    
    page_list = soup.find_all(class_='mulu-list')
    pages = page_list[0].find_all('a')
    print(pages[0])
    for i in range(len(pages)):
        pages[i] = pages[i].get('href')
        
    with open("{}1.txt".format(bookname), "w+") as file_object:
        for i in range(len(pages)):
            file_object.write('\n\n\t{}'.format(i+1))
            page = requests.get(pages[i])
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
            content = soup.find(class_='neirong').text
            print(content[0:20])
            file_object.write(content)

    with open("{}1.txt".format(bookname)) as oldfile, open("{}1.txt".format(bookname), 'w') as newfile:
        for line in oldfile:
            if not ('adsbygoogle' in line):
                newfile.write(line)    


scraping_novel("shediaoyingxiongzhuan","射雕英雄傳")                


#failed
```

There're two things I've tried:

1. switching file name from Chinese to English as I thought it could be some issues with encoding, and it doesn't help. In fact this is NOT the first time I scrape non-English website, and I've never seen something like this.
2. In the first **With** statements, the second last line, print(content[0:20]), I was trying to check for the content. It was completely fine, so I think the issue is not with BS, but the file writing. There's nothing written in the output file! Btw, output file size is zero byte.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me what's happening, as I still couldn't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Btw, there're no error messages.

Comment: `open("{}1.txt".format(bookname), 'w') as newfile` should become `open("{}.txt".format(bookname), 'w') as newfile` I think. Looks like a copy&paste error.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke even with your change, I was starting at it, and couldn't see it... for an embarrassingly long time :-)

Comment: @user9882001 diff -b or -w should tell you easily.

Comment: OK, as the two answers now agree on the fact that this issue was caused by a typo, the question should be closed.

Comment: Thank you very much Lydia. This is awkward...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("1.txt", "w+") as oldfile:
    oldfile.write('test')

differentName = "12.txt"
with open("1.txt", "r") as oldfile, open(differentName, 'w') as newfile:
    assert(len(oldfile.readlines()))     

sameName = "1.txt"
with open(sameName, "r") as oldfile, open(sameName, 'w') as newfile:
    assert(len(oldfile.readlines()))
```

The typo @**Lydia van Dyke** mentioned leads to the file being opened for writing and ending the reading stream early. So the loop over the lines of oldfile gets executed 0 times.

Answer (score 0):

Working with python >= 3.6?
Do

```
open(f"{bookname}.txt", 'w') as newfile
```

However for the overwriting of the file. I'm guessing you cannot do that. Your opening the same file for reading and writing in one statement.